# EnumHeader expected

Tags: java, eclipse

I am making a sound visualizer and I have this error : `Syntax errors on tokens,EnumHeader expected instead`
This is the code:

```
  import ddf.minim.analysis.*;
import java.lang.Object;
import java.net.*;
import ddf.minim.*;
import sun.audio.*;;
Minim minim;
AudioPlayer jingle;
FFT fft;
AudioInput in;
float[] angle;
float[] y, x;

void setup()
{
  size(screen.width, screen.height, P3D){{
  minim = new Minim(this);
  in = minim.getLineIn(Minim.STEREO, 2048, 192000.0);
  fft = new FFT(in.bufferSize(), in.sampleRate());
  y = new float[fft.specSize()];
  x = new float[fft.specSize()];
  angle = new float[fft.specSize()];
  frameRate(240);
}};
```

I tried with all the accessors but nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

Members and method declarations must be inside classes (or enums) in Java:

```
import ddf.minim.analysis.*;
import java.lang.Object;
import java.net.*;
import ddf.minim.*;
import sun.audio.*;

public class SomeClass { // Here!

    Minim minim;
    AudioPlayer jingle;
    FFT fft;
    AudioInput in;
    float[] angle;
    float[] y, x;

    void setup()
    {
      size(screen.width, screen.height, P3D){{
      minim = new Minim(this);
      in = minim.getLineIn(Minim.STEREO, 2048, 192000.0);
      fft = new FFT(in.bufferSize(), in.sampleRate());
      y = new float[fft.specSize()];
      x = new float[fft.specSize()];
      angle = new float[fft.specSize()];
      frameRate(240);
    }
}
```